# next(), closest() and find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I have the following HTML markup,

```
<section>
    <img width="106" height="113" title="key-staff-tim" alt="key-staff-tim" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://wp-content/uploads/2011/07/key-staff-tim.jpg">              
    <article class="biography visible" style="display: block;">
        <h3>Director</h3>
        <p>Aliquam sagittis purus vitae turpis elementum sed congue lectus tempor. Integer eleifend vestibulum tristique. Pellentesque ut risus leo. Duis tempus sollicitudin viverra. Pellentesque laoreet, justo ut dictum mattis, tellus odio dapibus lacus, convallis lobortis massa dolor nec quam.</p>
        <p>Aliquam sagittis purus vitae turpis elementum sed congue lectus tempor. Integer eleifend vestibulum tristique. Pellentesque ut risus leo. Duis tempus sollicitudin viverra. Pellentesque laoreet, justo ut dictum mattis, tellus odio dapibus lacus, convallis lobortis massa dolor nec quam.</p>
    </article>

 <img width="107" height="114" title="key-staff-chris" alt="key-staff-chris" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://wp-content/uploads/2011/07/key-staff-chris.jpg">               
    <article class="biography" style="top: 300px;">
        <h3>Director</h3>
            <p>Aliquam sagittis purus vitae turpis elementum sed congue lectus tempor. Integer eleifend vestibulum tristique. Pellentesque ut risus leo. Duis tempus sollicitudin viverra. Pellentesque laoreet, justo ut dictum mattis, tellus odio dapibus lacus, convallis lobortis massa dolor nec quam.</p>
             <p>Aliquam sagittis purus vitae turpis elementum sed congue lectus tempor. Integer eleifend vestibulum tristique. Pellentesque ut risus leo. Duis tempus sollicitudin viverra. Pellentesque laoreet, justo ut dictum mattis, tellus odio dapibus lacus, convallis lobortis massa dolor nec quam.</p>
    </article>

<img width="106" height="113" title="key-staff-nic" alt="key-staff-nic" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="wp-content/uploads/2011/07/key-staff-nic.jpg">             

    <article class="biography" style="top: 300px;">
        <h3>Designer</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet.</p>
    </article>
<img width="109" height="112" title="key-staff-claire" alt="key-staff-claire" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="http://wp-content/uploads/2011/07/key-staff-claire.jpg">             
     <article class="biography" style="top: 300px;">
         <h3>Account Manager</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet.</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet auctor varius. Mauris venenatis, enim sit amet faucibus pharetra cras amet.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

What I want to do with the jQuery below is, when an image is clicked, I want to identify the next `.biography` in the DOM and animate and add class. I assume I will have to use, `find()`, `.closest()` or `.next()`. I have tried all of them below is my current attempt.

```
$('.the-team img').click(function(){
    //var clickedImage = $(this);
    $('.visible').animate({"top" : $('.the-team').height()+10 }, 1000).removeClass('visible').fadeOut(5);
    $(this).find().next('article.biography').addClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: Could be me but where is the element having  the "the-team" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).next('article.biography').addClass('visible').animate({"top" : $('.the-team').height()+10 }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, you don't need to call find() first.
The find() function will search all descendants of the given dom element(s). Next will just search the the next element on the same level.

So just use:

```
$(this).next('article.biography').addClass('visible');
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 .next('article.biography')
```

To:

```
 .nextAll('article.biography:first')
```

Next means: look at the next element, and return it if it matches the selector. If not, return nothing. It does not look farther than the very next element.

nextAll check all of them, then you use :first to just get the first match.

It's a common error.

Answer (score 0):

just try-

```
 $(this).find('article').hasClass(".biography").addClass('visible');
```